# Problem with small Breakpoint in Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have various breakpoints in my Bootstrap Grid. Small and Medium. But the small breakpoint does not work, I don't see any diference.

```
<div class="form-row">              
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 form-group">
              <b>Geburtsname:</b>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 form-group">
              Mustermann
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 form-group ">
              <b>Staatsangehörigkeit:</b>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 form-group">
             deutsch
              </div>
              </div>
```

I don't get the wanted effects with small devices. With not the sm Breakpoint I have the same effects here. What can I do?

What is the problem here?

[That is ok! (medium)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaMrk.jpg)

[That is the problem (small resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn6rr.jpg)

Comment: may be you misinterpreted devices to be small and still looking at medium display device?

Comment: @JoJo123 Your code works correctly, however, its the Text that is long and overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the word `Staatsangehörigkeit` is too long to be accomodated in the provided column width in `sm` size.

If you are using latest Bootstrap v4.3, you can use the utility class `.text-break` (Refer: [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#word-break)) and apply to the column where issue occurs. It will break the word to second line.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 form-group text-break">
    <b>Staatsangehörigkeit:</b>
</div>
```

If you are using older versions of Bootstrap, you can create the same class in your custom CSS and then apply.

```
.text-break {
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please add a class "row" in parent div. Check below:

```
<div class="form-row row">              
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 form-group">
        <b>Geburtsname:</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 form-group">
        Mustermann
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 form-group ">
        <b>Staatsangehörigkeit:</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 form-group">
        deutsch
    </div>
</div>
```